# Algebraic solution of quartic complex equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

The below problem is taken from the text by: James Victor Uspensky, titled: Theory of Equations; sec. [1.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0AA0.png).

> Finding the algebraic solution of the complex equation:
> $$x^4= -16i.$$

Substituting the real and imaginary parts, as a & b respectively:

$(a+bi)^4 = -16i$

$a^4 +b^4i^4 + 4a^3bi + 6a^2b^2i^2 +4ab^3i^3 = -16i$

$a^4 +b^4 +4a^3bi -6a^2b^2 -4ab^3i = -16i $  --(a)

Separating the real and imaginary parts,

$a^4 + b^4 -6a^2b^2$ = 0                         --(b)

$4a^3bi - 4ab^3i = -16i$                     --(c)

=> $a^3b -ab^3 = -4$

=> $ab^3 - a^3b = 4    $

=> $ab(b^2 - a^2) = 4      $

=> $ab(b-a)(b+a) = 4         $                  --(c)

Dividing (b) by $b^4$, and setting x = $a/b$; we get:

=> $x^4 +1 -6x^2 = 0 $

Setting $y= x^2$

=> $y^2 + 1 -6y = 0 $                              --(b)

I am unable to solve it further, by proceeding from either (b) or (c). Also, any substitution of the roots of (c) into (b) is not working too.

Comment: You have the wrong approach. Use the polar representation of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an algebraic solution you can use the following reasoning.

Solve the following equation
$$(x^4+16i)(x^4-16i)=0$$
and take the needed roots only.

We need to solve
$$x^8+256=0$$  and LHS it's
$$(x^4+16)^2-32x^4$$ or
$$(x^4-4\sqrt2x^2+16)(x^4+4\sqrt2x^2+16)$$ or
$$((x^2+4)^2-(8+4\sqrt2)x^2)((x^2+4)^2-(8-4\sqrt2)x^2)$$ and we need to solve
$$\left(x^2-2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}x+4\right)\left(x^2+2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}x+4\right)\left(x^2-2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}x+4\right)\left(x^2+2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}x+4\right)=0,$$
which after solving of four quadratic equations gives the following roots:
$$x_1=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_3=-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_4=-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_5=\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_6=\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i,$$
$$x_7=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i $$ and
$$x_8=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i.$$
Now, $$x_2^4=\left( \sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i\right)^4=\left(\left( \sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i\right)^2\right)^2=$$
$$=\left(2+\sqrt2-2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i-(2-\sqrt2)\right)^2=$$
$$=\left(2\sqrt2-2\sqrt{4-2}i\right)^2=8(1-i)^2=-16i.$$
Thus, since $i^4=1$ and $(-1)^4=1$, we get all roots of the equation $x^4=-16i$:
$$\{x_2,-x_2, x_2i, -x_2i\}$$ or
$$\left\{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i,\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i,-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i\right\}.$$
Done!

The last root it's $$-x_2i=-\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i\right)i=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}i.$$

Comment: Quick sanity check: From the 8 solutions, how one can find the 4 required solution? Is there any easier way? (+1) Of course, very elegant.

Comment: @Krish We know that $i^4=1$ and $(-1)^4=1$. Thus, it's enough to find one  root $a$ only and we can get all roots: $\{a,-a,ai,-ai\}$. I found that $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i$ is valid and the rest you saw.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I wish you had completed the solution, as it is a novel approach, and so too much to ask for hints each time one is stuck.

Comment: @jiten By my previous comment it's enough to prove that $\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i\right)^4=-16i$. I am ready to show it. it's easy. Maybe is there another questions?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Starting with, your equation has the leftmost equation: $\left(x^2-2\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}x+4\right)$. Its equation has solution according to me: $\left\{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\pm\sqrt{\sqrt2 -2}\right\}.$ I cannot see how the term 'i' is generated in the latter radical.

Comment: @jiten I added something. See now. Actually, $\sqrt2-2<0$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Continuing in detail, the quadratic has roots: $\frac{2\sqrt {2+\sqrt2}\pm\sqrt{4\sqrt2-8}}{2}$=${\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\pm\sqrt{\sqrt2 -2}}$. I see no need to get 'i' generated, as to me: +4*(-2)=-8, and (-2) is still inside the radical sign.

Comment: @jiten $\sqrt{\sqrt2-2}=\sqrt{-(2-\sqrt2)}=\pm\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}i$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66086/discussion-between-jiten-and-michael-rozenberg).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Then the visually more correct way to write is:   $x_1=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}\pm i\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}$. I hope am correct.

Comment: @jiten No! I see your teacher teaches you not right! If in the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ we have $a\neq0$ and $\Delta<0$ then $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$. Try to use it for our equation and you'll don't get any contradiction. By the way, I think you understood my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I felt that I ended the confusion by taking 'i' outside in a visually more clear manner. But, there is more confusion added by not having '-' sign before the discriminant's root. I don't feel you meant that. It is obvious that even for imaginary discriminant, there will be 2 (based on both $\pm)$ roots under consideration.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I am also similarly asking you to accept that my visually more clear way to place 'i' before the second radical expression is better.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Sorry, but your statement about ignoring the -ve sign of discriminant is valid only for it being a complex number, and not for a -ve real. A -ve real has both $\pm i \sqrt \Delta$ values being stated explicitly.  But, for a complex no. under the square root, only the $ + \sqrt \Delta$ is stated. The reason is square root of a complex no. generates both +ve and -ve values automatically. My source is Complex Analysis and Applications (2nd edn.), by Allan Jeffrey, page #20, 21.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I have accepted it. I hope that other issues can be sorted out now.

Comment: @jiten Thenk you! It's just depends on definition of $i$ and $\sqrt{-1}$. I like $\sqrt{-1}=\{i,-i\}$ and $i^2=-1$ because if you want for example to calculate $\sqrt{2i}$ the you'll get $\sqrt{2i}=\{1+i,-1-i\}$. So why $\sqrt{-1}$ is better?

Answer (score 1):

$x^4=-16i=\frac{16}{i}$
$x=\frac{16^\frac{1}{4}}{i^\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2}{(e^{i\pi/2)^\frac{1}{4}}}=2e^{-(i\pi/2+2k\pi)/4};\quad k\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: Small error in the last equality.

Comment: @ZachBoyd ....?

Comment: The 2kpi just needs to be divided by 4. I can explain why if you disagree.

Comment: @ZachBoyd thanks for correcting, is it correct now?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: @jiten are you just asking if there is a way without using polar coordinates?

Comment: @ZachBoyd: Yes, I want an algebraic solution which deliberately (for knowledge sake) does not touch the polar coordinates, & works algebraically only.

Comment: This would be good to put in as an edit to the question posting, so you can hopefully attract answers of the kind you want. Not very many people read these comments. I will see if there is time for me to look at it more.

Comment: @ZachBoyd: Thanks in anticipation for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Take the principal root:

$$x^4 = -16i \ \ ||()^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$x = 2(e^{-i\pi/2})^\frac{1}{4}$$
$$x = 2e^{-i\pi/8}$$

Now, with the principal root and by properties of algebraic solutions to complex equations, can you find any other roots?

Answer (score 1):

From your equation (b), you have $$(a^2-b^2)^2 -4a^2b^2 = 0$$
then $(a^2-2ab-b^2)(a^2+2ab-b^2)=0$.

From equation (c), you have $ab(b^2-a^2) = 4$.

Case 1:  $a^2-2ab-b^2 = 0$ and $ab(b^2-a^2) = 4$. You get $(ab)^2=2$, then $ab=\sqrt{2}$ or $ab=-\sqrt{2}$.

For $ab=2$, $b^2-a^2=2\sqrt{2}$. Then $\frac{2}{a^2}-a^2=2\sqrt{2}$, you get $a^4+2\sqrt{2}a^2-2=0$, then $a^2=-\sqrt{2}+2$, so $b^2=\sqrt{2}+2$.

I leave the rest cases for you.